# Create Symbolic Link for Windows Machines

Tags: windows, samba, symlink, compatibility

I currently operate a SMB file server for my network and, like a lot of you guys, don't touch Windows myself. I need to create a symbolic link that will work on my user's Windows machine to `\\SERVER\\public`.

On UNIX/Linux; we can run `ln -s [from] [to]` — I don't think this type of link would work if I am doing it for a Windows machine.

Is there any application for Linux that would help me create a Windows link to the location above?

Thank you.

Comment: a .lnk file to the destination? can be opened by the windows explorer.exe.

Comment: How would I create one of those from within UNIX/Linux?

Comment: `.lnk` file is not a sym-link, it does not work in the same way. It is however similar: it only works with some applications, it will only do one hop. NTFS does support sym-links, however they are disabled by default, and managing of them may not be supported by your software.

Comment: I just created a sym-link on my `ntfs` `usb` storage. It just worked. (don't know about `smb` or `cifs`.

Comment: Wow; just retried it and it worked. Haha, fancy that one. Thanks for getting me to retry that one.